# Dynamically Create div with centred user specified text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Goal:

1. user gives input (name and size)
2. presses a button
3. a draggable object of specified size is created with the name centered

So far I have been able to create a draggable object upon button click, and put a static string `<p>Task</p>` horizontally lined inside this object.

Question: How do I dynamically change the size of this draggable object based on user input, and replace the static "text" with the name given by the user?

Code:
As you can see I am adding Task in the .append() when I am creating the draggable object. I assume this would work: 
`"...<p id=Task>"+userGivenName+"</p>`? 
However even if this works I am unable to centre the text inside the draggable object.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


<link href="_css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
.makeMeDraggable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;

}
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#Task {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

</style>

<script>

$('document').ready(function(){
  $("#create_block").click(function(){
    $('.tasker').append($("<div class='makeMeDraggable'><p>id=Task>Task</div>"));
    $('.makeMeDraggable' ).draggable().css({
      'width': '50px', //set width
      'height': '50px' //set height
    });
    $('#Task').position({
      my: "center",
      at: "bottom",
      of: ".makeMeDraggable"
    });
  });//end click
  $('.makeMeDraggable').draggable().hide();

});//end ready
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
        <h1>Draggable Task</h1>
        <a class = "button" id="create_block">Create Task</a>
        <div class="tasker">
          <div class="makeMeDraggable">
            <p id = Task>Task</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet or a jsfiddle for your code.

Comment: That is the entire code except for external .css that has info about "wrapper"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should not use code that generates multiple elements with same id. That's always going to create hard to debug errors.

Secondly, I believe your code could be simplified. See snippet below.

As for centering your text and auto-width, simply setting display to `inline-block`, not specifying a `width` or `height` and setting `text-align` to `center` should do the trick:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#create_block").click(function() {
    if ($('input[name="task"]').val().length) {
      let width = $('input[name="width"]').val() > 0 ? 
          'width:' + $('input[name="width"]').val() + 'px;':'', 
          height = $('input[name="height"]').val() > 0 ? 
          'height:' + $('input[name="height"]').val() + 'px;':'';
      $('.tasker').append($("<div />", {
        class: 'makeMeDraggable',
        html: '<p>' + $('input[name="task"]').val() + '</p>',
        style: width + height
      }).draggable());
      $('input').val('');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.makeMeDraggable {
  position: absolute !important;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tasker {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Draggable Task</h1>
      <input name="task" type="text" placeholder="task name; cannot be empty"/><br />
      <input name="width" type="number" placeholder="width; empty for auto"/><br />
      <input name="height" type="number" placeholder="height; empty for auto" /><br />
      <button id="create_block">Create Task</button>
      
      <div class="tasker"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side note: setting `.makeMeDraggable`'s position to `absolute` is not going to do anything, as `.draggable()` will set it to `relative`. If you set `!important` on the rule and try to center the tasks initially inside `tasker` using `transform:translateX(-50%)`, the tasks will jump to the left by `50%` of their width each time you start dragging them around, which is probably not desired.

However, `display:flex` on `.tasker` seems to work for this purpose. (Updated snippet with flex centering).

Comment: @algoBaller, see note added to answer and updated snippet, if you are looking for a way to center the tasks when created. You're welcome. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)

Comment: Hello @Andrei Gheorghiu, what if I wanted to select the width/height of the .makeMeDraggable manually? I.E. each time the box is different depending on user input

Comment: Add more inputs/select elements to the page to let the user input or select from existing options. You can read their values using `.val()`, like in the snippet. Just add `style` to the object and use those values.

Comment: @algoBaller, I updated the answer with how to add optional `width` and `height`. Also changed `inline-block` to `inline-flex` to allow vertical centering of content (when changing default height)

Comment: thank you for your help, I still have much to learn! but this was exactly what I was looking for. Best Regards

Comment: @algoBaller, if that's the case, consider marking the answer as "accepted". Also, as a general rule, make a habit of up-voting any helpful answers to your questions, to thank people for helping you. Everyone here volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for, but relative electors with using classes instead of id's work fine.  You can't assign multiple divs the same id, because only one will work properly, instead use classes.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  $("#create_block").click(function(){
    $("<div><p class='Task'>Task</div>")
      .appendTo('.tasker')
      .draggable().css({
        'width': '50px', //set width
        'height': '50px' //set height
      })
      .find(".Task")
      .position({
        my: "center",
        at: "bottom",
        of: ".makeMeDraggable"
      });
  });//end click
  $('.makeMeDraggable').draggable().hide();

});//end ready
```

```css
.makeMeDraggable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;

}
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.Task {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="main">
      <h1>Draggable Task</h1>
      <a class = "button" id="create_block">Create Task</a>
      <div class="tasker">
        <div class="makeMeDraggable">
          <p class="Task">Task</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```